# Python - partitioning a list of strings using an equivalence relation

Tags: python

I have a list of alphabetic strings `[str1,str2,...]` which I need to partition into equivalence classes using an equivalence relation R, where `str1 R str2` (in relational notation) if `str2` can be obtained from `str1` by a sequence of valid one-letter changes, where 'valid' means it produces a valid alphabetic word, e.g. `cat --> car` is valid but `cat --> 'cax` is not.  If the input list was `['cat','ace','car','zip','ape','pip']` then the code should return `[['cat','car'],['ace','ape'],['zip','pip']]`.

I've got an initial working version which, however, produces some "classes" which contain duplicates.

I don't suppose there is any Python package which allows me to define such equivalence relations, but even otherwise what would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: What is the expected output for `["cat", "car", "bar"]`?

Comment: Why not `[['car', 'bar'], ['cat']`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it would be `["cat", "car", "bar"]`, there would be one class in this example.

Comment: But `"bar"` cannot be turned into `"cat"` by changing one letter...

Comment: Let me clarify: it would be via a sequence of valid one-letter changes.  So `bar` follows from `cat` via the sequence `bar --> car --> cat`.

Comment: Please read the question description carefully: The author pointed out that R is an **equivalence relation**, therefore R is reflexive, symmetric and transitive. The most important here is a transitivity which means when you have three strings `str1`, `str2`, `str3` and you know that `str1 R str2 and str2 R str3` then you can say that `str1 R str3`.

Comment: That's right, if by changing one letter in `str1` you get an invalid word then you go back to `str1` and try with another letter that has not been used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it something like this: construct an undirected graph where each word is a node, and each edge indicates that the relation holds between them. Then you can identify each disconnected "island" in the graph, each of which represents an equivalence class.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def exactly_one(iter):
    count = 0
    for x in iter:
        if x:
            count += 1
            if count > 1: 
                break
    return count == 1

def are_one_letter_apart(a,b):
    if len(a) != len(b): return False
    return exactly_one(a_char != b_char for a_char, b_char in zip(a,b))

def pairs(seq):
    for i in range(len(seq)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(seq)):
            yield (seq[i], seq[j])

def search(graph, node):
    seen = set()
    to_visit = set()
    to_visit.add(node)
    while to_visit:
        cur = to_visit.pop()
        if cur in seen: continue
        for neighbor in graph[cur]:
            if neighbor not in seen:
                to_visit.add(neighbor)
        seen.add(cur)
    return seen

def get_islands(graph):
    seen = set()
    islands = []
    for item in graph.iterkeys():
        if item in seen: continue
        group = search(graph, item)
        seen = seen | group
        islands.append(group)
    return islands

def create_classes(seq, f):
    graph = defaultdict(list)
    for a,b in pairs(seq):
        if f(a,b):
            graph[a].append(b)
            graph[b].append(a)
    #one last pass to pick up items with no relations to anything else
    for item in seq:
        if item not in graph:
            graph[item].append(item)

    return [list(group) for group in get_islands(graph)]

seq = ['cat','ace','car','zip','ape','pip']
print create_classes(seq, are_one_letter_apart)
```

Result:

```
[['ace', 'ape'], ['pip', 'zip'], ['car', 'cat']]
```

Comment: OK, seems to work for that three-letter word list here is a five-letter word list `['bread','breed', 'bream', 'tread', 'treat', 'short', 'shorn', 'shirt', 'shore', 'store','eagle','mired', ''sired', 'hired']`, but the output is `[['shorn', 'shore', 'short', 'shirt'], ['treat', 'tread', 'bread'], ['sired', 'hired', 'mired'], ['breed', 'bread'], ['bream', 'bread'], ['shore', 'store']]`, which seems incorrect because there is a valid sequence `'bread' --> 'bream'`, they should be in the same class.

Comment: Oops, there was a typo in `search`. Try it now.

Comment: Seems to work.  Surprised there is no Python graphs related package which does things like this, or is there?

Comment: What's the `|` symbol, a boolean operator?

Comment: In this context, it gets the [union of the two sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28set_theory%29).

Comment: It seems `pairs(seq)` could be rewritten using `itertools.combinations(iter, tuple_size)`, but I suppose that would that defeat the purpose of your using `yield` to reduce memory overhead.

Comment: There is a small error in your code: it will not pick up isolated nodes, i.e. those which are related only to themselves, not to other nodes.  For example, if the list was `['to', 'tot', 'top']` the result is `['tot','top']`, but in this list there is a singleton class `['to']`, because `'to'` is related to itself.

What is needed are two lines in `create_classes(seq, f)` which are 

    `graph[a].append(a)`
    `graph[b].append(b)`

Comment: @ramius, good observation that 'to' doesn't appear in the output. I prefer doing a final pass to add isolated nodes rather than appending them from inside the `pairs` loop, if only because the latter uses a little more memory, I think.

Answer (score 3):

Should work for different length strings. Obviously, ordering matters.

```
def is_one_letter_different(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) != len(s2):
        return False
    diff_count = 0;
    for char1, char2 in zip(s1, s2):
        if char1 != char2:
            diff_count += 1
    return diff_count == 1

def group(candidates):
    groups = []
    for candidate in candidates:
        for group in groups:
            for word in group:
                if is_one_letter_different(word, candidate):
                    group.append(candidate)
                    break
            if candidate in group:
                break
        else:
            groups.append([candidate])
    return groups

print group(['bread','breed', 'bream', 'tread', 'treat', 'short', 'shorn', 'shirt', 'shore', 'store','eagle','mired', 'sired', 'hired'])
```

Output:

```
[['bread', 'breed', 'bream', 'tread', 'treat'], ['short', 'shorn', 'shirt', 'shore', 'store'], ['eagle'], ['mired', 'sired', 'hired']]
```

EDIT: Updated to follow additional testcases. I'm not sure of output correctness - please validate. And provide us good testcases next time.

Comment: `group(['bread', 'breed', 'bream'])` gives `[['bread', 'breed'], ['bream']]` which is incorrect because `'bread'` and `'bream'` are in a relation.

Comment: But in data structure presented by OP relations are flat and sequential, so `bread` may be in relation with either `bread` or `bream`, not simultaneously. And that's when ordering of input comes to play. For me clearly either problem is stated incorrectly or testcases (expected input -> expected output) are broken.

Comment: The author defined that R is an [equivalence relation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29233760/python-partitioning-a-list-of-strings-using-an-equivalence-relation#comment46674358_29233760), therefore `group(['bread', 'breed', 'bream'])` should result with one class.

Comment: OK, the problem description was as given to me, I cannot change or really ask for more info, but `'breed'` and `'bream'` are children of the node `'bread'`, each edge represents a different move sequence: `'bread' --> 'bream'` and `'bread' --> 'breed'`.